# Magento 2: Add Image to the Customer Account Navigation Menu

Tags: php, magento, magento-2.0, magento-2.3, magento2.2

I hope everyone is doing well!

[image: Menu]

I am new to Magento 2. I would like to add Image for all the menus in **"Customer Account Navigation Menu"** at the top of each link.
I am able to change the text of the Link but don't know how to add Image.

I request you all, please take a look at the highlighted part where I would like to add images for each link and properly guide me through this.
Thank you in advance.

**Stay Home Stay Safe!**